# Mkdir working for one folder but not the other in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

This is probably a simple fix but I wrote a bash script to create two directories with one of those being a sub-directory of the other. I will link the script below. It creates the "/usr/local/sites" just fine but it won't create the A-upgrade below that directory for some reason. Any thoughts?

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=/usr/local/sites/
SITE=A
sudo mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY"
sudo mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY/$SITE-upgrade/"
cd "$DIRECTORY/$SITE-upgrade/"
```

Comment: Try `sudo mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY/${SITE}-upgrade/"` and cd `"$DIRECTORY/${SITE}-upgrade/"` Also change shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` too see what everything expands to.

Comment: @FredrikPihl That did not do the trick either.

Comment: @AAlred Add an `echo $?` after the last `mkdir` command and see what error code it returns.

Comment: What output did `-x` provide?

Comment: @hnefatl It outputted a '0' afterwards

Comment: @DanFarrell derp, I just realized what happened.

Comment: @hnefatl read my answer below. It will probably give you a good laugh

Comment: Glad you solved it. Good luck with the rest :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks for the help! I am sure I will be back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After help from the others in the comments, I stupidly realized that I had a cleanup function in my script that was deleting my directory, which is what it was suppose to do. Thanks again for the help guys. Sometimes it helps to add a "-x". The cleanup directory did the following and was deleting the directory I was searching for.

```
log "cleaning up folder"
log "cd up a directory"
cd ..
log "remove folder $SITE-upgrade"
find "$SITE-upgrade" -type d | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: You should [mark this as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @hnefatl It won't let me for two days, after that I will

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18381846)

Comment: @BenHare In what way does this not provide an answer? I explain that I had a cleanup function written in my bash script that was deleting the directory after I had created it and that is why it was not showing that directory.

Comment: Just seems to me that this is a comment on or edit to the question; not an actual answer. No one can come back to this question later and use it to help with their own problem since you haven't provided all the information in the question - notably that there is this cleanup function somewhere in your script. I would edit the entire script including that into the question, then point out the part of it that caused the problem in the answer - that might be able to help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have $SITE in the sudo statement instead of $SITES, which is the variable you assigned to above the sudo statement.

Comment: That is a typo on my part. It is actually SITE in the code haha